# Access IIS https website from outside network

Tags: azure, iis, networking, webserver, azure-virtual-machine

Currently I have a https website setup locally on the Azure VM
with a custom hostname : `<websitename>.<domainname>.com` and bound to the localhost `127.0.0.2`
in the hosts.etc on `port 443`

Consider example hostname as `web.microsoft.com`

Website bindings in IIS are

```
type:https
hostname:web.microsoft.com
port:443
IP Address:127.0.0.2
```

Hosts.etc

```
127.0.0.2   web.microsoft.com
```

In order to access it locally on the VM itself `https://web.microsoft.com/admin/login.aspx` works fine.

`Port 443` is open on the Azure VM and inbound firewall rule is set in windows to allow connections on `443`

If I try to access it outside of the network using the public IP address this doesn't work
eg `https://45.60.200.110/admin/login.aspx`.
[image]

I have other non-https websites which work fine and can be accessed through the public IP ,only difference is they are not having hostname in the IIS website bindings.

Am I missing something or do I need to make some additional config?

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: You can try to use http access, if it works, it means that the problem is the https connection. Or continue to use https, but set a default static page for the site. Another thing, does the custom hostname defined by yourself? Or you buy it from domain provider?

Comment: @BruceZhang Its defined by myself.

Answer (score 1):

That's the problem.

The customized hostname cannot be accessed through the external network. Because the public network does not know this hostname, nor does it bind the hostname to your IP.

For example, you can enter other custom host names at will in the browser, and you will find the same error displayed.

The solution is that you need to purchase an available public domain name from the domain name provider and bind it to IP address.

If you insist on using custom domain name, it can only be used on the internal network. In addition to the configuration made on the server side, it is also need to add the host name and IP address in the hosts file of the client machine.

```
45.60.200.110  web.microsoft.com
```